# Get address without spending gas

Tags: solidity, contract-development, solidity-0.8.x

I am writing a contract that lets users sign up for a raffle, then select a few of them using chainlinks VRF. To save users on gas I'm letting users sign up by simply adding their address to a list, then on my end calling a function to scrub the list of duplicates and other requirements (min balance etc). Is there a way to get a participants address without them spending any gas at all?

I know there are many ways off chain, but what about on chain? Is there a way for an EOA to sign/send a message to a contract without spending gas?

Comment: There are meta transactions. It is not the same, but it allows users to use a provider send transaction on their behalf, the contract has to be modified in order to understand this type of transactions. See https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/63180/meta-transaction-explanation.

Answer (score 1):

No, someone will at the least need to pay min txn cost (21K) + storage cost for the SLOADs of the addresses being added to the contract. You can have a web interface where they sign and send a message off-chain to you and you bulk-add their addresses to the contract in one transaction, but the chain cannot interoperate with signatures via view functions (the only gasless way to interact with the chain).